# Update the table 1 column with the values of table 2 colum

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update the table 1 column with the table 2 column value. So I try doing this in mySQL

```
UPDATE location_role_user 
SET location_role_user.TENANT_CODE = usr.TENANT_CODE 
FROM 
    users usr
  JOIN 
    users  ON  location_role_user.LOGIN_ID = usr.LOGIN_ID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using SQL Server update join syntax.  The MySQL version looks like this:

```
UPDATE location_role_user lru
INNER JOIN users usr
   ON lru.LOGIN_ID = usr.LOGIN_I
SET
    lru.TENANT_CODE = usr.TENANT_CODE;
```

Comment: @kevin_marcus If this warrants a 'wow', just wait and see what (my)sql can really do. It will blow your mind.

Comment: @Strawberry haha! I can foresee it now. I'm just learning by myself now. I graduated as a nurse and now trying to do programming.

Comment: @kevin_marcus Cheers on graduating, and feel free to come back here anytime you need more help!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with ease using the following query.

```
UPDATE location_role_user loc INNER JOIN users usr 
    ON loc.LOGIN_ID = usr.LOGIN_ID
    SET loc.TENANT_CODE = usr.TENANT_CODE;
```

Comment: I don't see what duplicating existing answers adds to the conversation

Comment: While answering the Question. Accepted answer was not here. That's why it seems to be duplicate

Comment: The accepted answer was there 20 minutes before yours. Just sayin'

Comment: so what I have not refreshed my page for 30min while answering the question. so it does not matter when the accepted answer was answered.

Answer (score -1):

Use a subquery:

```
UPDATE location_role_user
SET location_role_user.TENANT_CODE=
(SELECT usr.TENANT_CODE FROM usr WHERE location_role_user.LOGIN_ID = usr.LOGIN_ID);
```